# PHP Quiz without Database Need to use this Array system

Tags: php, arrays, session

I just started using PHP and I have some problems. When the page loads I want it too load question 1 from the array. After submiting question 2 and so on. Here is my code: But I just get all the questions on screen.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['cQuestion'] = 1;
$questions = [
    [
        'question1' => 'Is de maan rond?',
        'answers' => ['Ja', 'Nee', 'Geen Idee'],
        'right_answers' => 0
    ],
    [
        'question2' => 'Is de maan vierkant?',
        'answers' => ['Ja', 'Nee', 'Geen Idee'],
        'right_answers' => 0
    ],

];


if (isset ($_SESSION['cQuestion'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['cQuestion'] == 1) {

        echo $questions[$_SESSION['cQuestion'] - 1]['question1'];
        $_SESSION['cQuestion']++;

    }
   elseif ($_SESSION['cQuestion'] == 2) {

        echo $questions[$_SESSION['cQuestion'] - 1]['question2'];
        $_SESSION['cQuestion']++;

    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Do `$_SESSION['cQuestion']++;` after `if-else`

Comment: I got question 1's statement on the screen.

Comment: Yes But I cant get the second question. If I use if in place of elseif I get the 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this happens, if I understand your question based on your comment, that you are always overwrite the counter.

When you initialize that, check, if is it set before. If yes, then leave it alone:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['cQuestion'])) {
    $_SESSION['cQuestion'] = 1;
}
```